# neo4J java query parameters

Tags: java, parameters, neo4j

I have a problem to pass list of string to my parameter {code}

```
String request = "START sdg=node:Sfamilly(master = {code}) MATCH t-[CONTAINS_SF]->sdg RETURN count(distinct t) as count"

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
codes.add("1234");
codes.add("12345");
params.put("master", codes);

Result<Map<String, Object>> resultMag = neo4jTemplate.query(request,params);
```

it appears that my parameters are not considered ?

Any idea ?

I use spring data neo4j rest 2.3.0.M1.

Thanks.
Charles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you wanted to say

```
params.put("code", codes); // on line 7
```

More importantly, it seems to me that passing lists is only supported when querying nodes by ID.

Not sure this is the best possible solution, but it should work. It builds a Lucene query first from your parameters, then passes it into your Neo4j query.

```
private void yourMethod() {
    String request = "START sdg=node:Sfamilly({luceneQuery}) MATCH t-[CONTAINS_SF]->sdg RETURN count(distinct t) as count";

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    List<String> codes = new ArrayList<String>();
    codes.add("1234");
    codes.add("12345");
    params.put("luceneQuery", listToParams("master", codes));

    Result<Map<String, Object>> resultMag = neo4jTemplate.query(request, params);
}

private String listToParams(String paramName, List<String> params) {
    if (params.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty params");
    }

    Iterator<String> paramsIterator = params.iterator();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(paramName).append(":").append(paramsIterator.next());

    while (paramsIterator.hasNext()) {
        builder.append(" OR ").append(paramName).append(":").append(paramsIterator.next());
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```